# When, if ever, is this approximation with the dirac delta function valid?

Tags: calculus, integration, dirac-delta

One of the properties of the dirac delta function is:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-a)f(x)dx=f(a)$$
Where here I am using the notation $\delta(x-a)$ to mean the spike at $x=a$

With all rigor, "it's not actually a function", and other arguments like this aside, I was wondering if the following approximation is ever valid:

$$\int_{x_0}^{\infty}\delta(x-a)f(x) \approx f(a)$$

Especially when using $$\delta(x-a)\approx \frac{e^{-(\frac{x-a}{b})^2}}{|b|\sqrt\pi}$$
When $b$ is made sufficiently small and $x_0<a$? Otherwise, the integral would be $0$ if $x_0>a$?

I have done a few numerical calculations with a variety of functions and it seems to hold up pretty well. Presumably if $f$ is particularly misbehaved then maybe this could have some problems, but I am not looking for functions that only exist as some counterexample in an analysis text. I am wondering whether or not this approximation is valid for well-behaved functions.

Comment: $\int_{x_0}^{\infty}\delta(x-a)f(x) \approx f(a)$ is not an approximation. It's an equality when $x_0<a.$ When $x_0>a$ it's just wrong unless $f(a)=0.$

Comment: Perhaps you meant to ask whether $\int_{x_0}^{\infty}D(x-a)f(x) \approx f(a),$ where $D$ approximates $\delta,$ e.g. $D(t) = e^{-(t/b)^2}/(|b|\sqrt\pi),$ where $|b|$ is small. In that case the answer is affirmative when $x_0<a$ but not when $x_0>a.$

Comment: Conditions on $f$ are that it's continuous at $a$ and that it doesn't grow too fast at infinity. For example, $f(x)=e^{cx^2}$ will make the integral not converge if $c$ is big enough.

Comment: Why write "With all rigor, "it's not actually a function", and other arguments like this aside"? There is no problem with rigorous rrasonnng when dealing with the Delta distribution ...

Comment: As the Dirac delta function is $0$ away from $a$, $\int_u^v \delta(x-a)f(x)\,dx = f(a)$ for all $u,v$ with $u < a < v$ and $\int_u^v \delta(x-a)f(x)\,dx$ when either $u \le v < a$ or $a < u \le v$. It is undefined when $u = a$ or $v = a$. This holds no matter how one chooses to make the concept rigorous (there are multiple ways of doing so - distributions are merely the most common). If your method does not support such an interpretation, then it has failed to truly model the concept.